# Any hints on getting Sitefinity CMS to work on medium trust?

Tags: .net, asp.net, content-management-system, medium-trust, sitefinity

We have been using Mosso / The Rackspace Cloud until very recently, but they have suddenly switched to a medium trust model for .NET for newly added sites and will be migrating existing server farms to medium trust shortly

We can't get our Sitefinity CMS V3.6 SP2 (the latest) to work in this environment.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to get [Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/) working under medium trust?

I have lodged a support ticket with Telerik as well and will report back if they come up with the goods.

The alternative will be to [move hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/33598/anyone-have-any-recommendations-for-cloud-server-farm-load-balanced-net-hosting).

Comment: Quog: What was your final resolution?

Comment: We gave up and moved to a host which could give us full trust.  We managed to get most things working in medium trust, even some sites completely worked, but there were certain key features that would never work in medium trust like workflows, search, certain custom module features we'd used.

Pity, because we really liked the Mosso approach to shared sites in a cloud (as opposed to most cloud services which are virtual private servers.)

Answer (score 4):

Slavo here from the team working on Sitefinity.

Someone from the team will reply to the support ticket you have submitted, but in the interest of anyone else that may have issues similar to yours, I wanted to write to you here as well. It doesn't become clear what problems exactly you have in your scenario, so I'll elaborate a bit on how Sitefinity works in a medium trust environment.

All of the features of Sitefinity are supported in such an environment, with minor exceptions. The main portion of code that requires full trust to run is the data access code. Sitefinity uses an ORM tool called Nolics.net to interact with the project database and supports automatic schema upgrades. A schema upgrade is required in the following scenarios:

- When you start your project for the first time (the database is empty)
- When you upgrade to a new version of Sitefinity (changed version of the Sitefinity assemblies)
- When you add a new data provider plugged into Sitefinity (more tables to add to the database)

Since hosting providers who run in medium trust will not let you change those settings, the solution is to perform these operations once on a development machine and then upload the changes to the production server.

If you haven't been able to run your project for the first time, chances are this is the reason. My advice would be to setup the project locally somewhere and run it, make sure you can browse the site and the administration interface, and then upload the project and the database (with already upgraded schema) with your hosting provider.

We also have guides on how to get started with [Discount ASP.NET](http://www.sitefinity.com/support/kb/sitefinity-3-x/discount-asp-net-hosting-provider.aspx) and [GoDaddy](http://www.sitefinity.com/support/kb/sitefinity-3-x/godaddy-asp-net-hosting-provider.aspx) as the most commonly used shared hosting providers. Maybe those could help.

If you still experience issues with your project, please provide more details, and I would be glad to help you here, or in our forums or support system.

Best,
Slavo

Comment: We've done exactly that - pushed the database and fileset from a development server running in full trust.  No joy I'm afraid.

Comment: FYI - we've also set workflow, pageworkflow and heartbeat to false and commented out the SitefinityXML provider, as per those documents.  Still get the Security Exception.

Comment: When do you get this security exception? The first time you launch the site? If you send us the web.config through the support system we'll try to reproduce the issue and provide better help.